# Animating color values in open gles 1.0 on Android

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es, colors

I am working on an application in which I will perform some drawing using openGL. In this application I will draw a 3d-object with *each vertex a different color*. This can be done by using a colorpointer.

Now, my problem is that I would like these colors to animate over time.
As the color values are given using a buffer, I would have to either recreate the buffer every frame with new colors, or replacing the values in the buffer somehow (which is probably quite error prone). I also thought about the possibility of using two buffers and switching between them (drawing with one buffer, and changing the other, then switch).
And in any case, I would have to upload the buffer to the video memory every frame...

So, my question is this; how do I, as efficient as possible, animate the different colors of an object in GL10?

**Note;** It would of course be easy to do this using shaders in gles 2.0, but I would prefer it if I could just use GL10 (or 11) for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using vertex colors, maybe you could come up with a clever way to use a texture instead, and animate this using the texture matrix? That way you wouldn't have to update your vertex buffers ever.

Comment: I was thinking about using textures, but the problem is that I (probably) would have to redraw the textures relatively often (and also upload the new texture to the video memory), which pretty much defeats my purpose of using opengl.